# Implementing access token architecture in my API

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, server

My app logic (Android, iOS and Web) is all written in my server.

Since things got complicated, I decided to build my server as a REST web service so querying it will contain logic in the header.

My login flow is pretty simple, and I somehow tried to copy from Facebook API:

1. The user login to Facebook.
2. The user receive a Facebook access token
3. The access token is sent to my server with some other identifiers
4. The server checks with Facebook that the access token is valid with Facebook and that the other identifiers match the ones on Facebook.
5. The server returns an access token to the user, which he should use in each query until it expires.

The problem is that I didn't add any other restrictions like endpoints limitations (scopes) and stuff like this, so an access token generated by my server grant you access to each part of my api.

I think that inventing the wheel here will be foolish, so I'm looking for a framework or a generic solution that will allow me to add logic to the access tokens in a simple way.

I read about OAuth, but my concern that its more about user sharing with other users, but I only want to use it is login flow and scope protector.

Is it possible with OAuth ? Are there alternative to OAuth ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's possible with OAuth 2.0 and in fact one of the objectives: you may issue and use access tokens that have particular "scopes" (an OAuth 2.0 concept) associated to them that could relate to permissions that the client has (e.g. read/write, API A, API B).

But you need to issue your own access tokens from your own Authorization Server. You could allow users to login to that Authorization Server with their Facebook account.

Comment: Can you expand on the flow? After my user logged in to my Api, what is the flow for geberating an OAuth access token with a scope?

Comment: all I read about OAuth is that its about letting the user the ability to share its details with 3rd party.. I just need it for a login flow..